# How to do 3d animation in iPhone using openGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, ios5

I am new to OpenGL ES. I was doing iOS development. Now I actually want to animate a 3d character. Can anyone help me out how I can animate it? I have some idea that it needs frames to animate. Can someone give me some sort of demo so I can work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great tutorial for animating graphics & making games.

http://www.lynda.com/tutorials/Building-and-Monetizing-Game-Apps-for-iOS/82407-2.html

Answer (score 1):

There are different techniques for character animations but the [skeletal-animation technique](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Skeletal_Animation) should be the best for characters. Using this technique requires some work:

- Load animation frames
- Interpolate animations
- Create animation matrices

This not gonna be easy, especially when you want to use facial animations you need techniques like [morph-targets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_target_animation) additional to the skeletal animation ( skeletal works here too, but it's hard to use ).

#### Side-note:

Animations are CPU expensive and should be used carefully when creating apps for iOS.

Comment: i am basically looking for some assistance you can say start up for opengl es for iPhone your answer is very general one it will be very helpful if you give any demo or tutorial about that . thanks for answer :)

Comment: I can't find any tutorials so i think there is no tutorial about animations on a iphone. This ( http://db-in.com/blog/2011/01/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-13/ ) is a good tutorial about OpenGL ES but it won't give you any help for the animation. Writing such a tutorial would take too much time. You could buy a book about OpenGL ( http://www.opengl.org/documentation/books/ ) there could also be animation code.